# Java FileReader try catch placement

Tags: java, try-catch

I am new to Java and just getting my head round FileReader/FileWriter but came across something i didn't understand so if someone could explain why this 1st try/catch doesn't work and the 2nd try/catch does?

Doesn't work

```
try{
    FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(filepath);
    filewriter.write(json.toString());
    saved = true;
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PresetData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Does work

```
try(FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(filepath)){
    filewriter.write(json.toString());
    saved = true;
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PresetData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

What difference does it make putting it there instead of in the try/catch?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message? If yes, then what is the exact error message? Does it compile, but do something else than you expected when you run it? If yes, then what exactly did you expect and what does it do differently?

Comment: If first doesn't work what error you get when you run the program ?

Comment: by doesnt work i meant does it successfully but nothing is written to file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example catches exceptions only, but never releases the resource.
You have to close it manually via calling the .close() function in a finally block: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close()

The 2nd example is called "try with resources" as you can read here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html
--> It will automatically call the .close() function for you, so you don't have to worry about resource leaks.

The exception handling via the catch-block is the same in both examples.